How to change/invert color of image texture
I would like these bricks to be white instead of black. Adding a color ramp or invert node causes it to lose the enamel quality that I am trying to maintain, and makes it greyish instead of white. I am using the Green Brick material from Blenderkit.
Thank you!




What do you mean by "enamel quality"?  Are you referring to the grout between each brick?

The shininess of the black brick! I'm less concerned with the grout

I believe your problem is that you don't have the factor of the Invert Color node all the way up to one.  Your third screenshot shows the Invert Color factor is set to ~0.483.
With the Invert Color node at zero, it just uses the original color.
Invert Color set to exactly 0.5 exactly blends the color halfway, leaving it completely washed out.Even turning the contrast up all the way on the Brightness/Contrast node makes no difference, as there isn't even any data to make more contrast-y.
Setting it all the way to 1 completely inverts the color, restoring the original contrast, but inverted.
I hope this clarifies your issues.  Unfortunately, I don't have the materiel you used, so it's hard to know if this is what you encountered.
